# Select empty bar in altair

Tags: altair, vega-lite, vega

Is it possible to select an empty bar in a chart on click using altair?

For example:

```
selection = alt.selection_single(fields=['x'])

ch1 = alt.Chart(ds2).mark_bar().encode(
x='y:Q',
y='x:O',
color=alt.condition(
    selection, 
    alt.value('#011B56'), 
    alt.value('lightgray'))

).add_selection(selection).properties(height=200)
```

[image: Example of selection]

Here you can see, that the third bar (from above) is chosen now. I'd like to be able to choose the second one and do other calculations further in another charts. But If I'm clicking now, that will be recognized that I'm clicking on a free space of the chart. That triggers, on the other hand, the event of selection's clearing.

Is there a way to select an empty bar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a vega-lite example where you can select on the y-axis even if there is no bar chart visible. Create a layer having a x-axis which covers the entire bar scale and make those bar transparent for that layer using `opacity: 0`. Since the opacity of the 2nd layer not visible, you can still perform selections on the empty space for y-axis. Below is the snippet and [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemhBQ5mJDVlwATooxwaZLGgBMYgAxK1SPWlDEkghnAhoA2qAB5IwsDLQBVAGUAQVN3Tzg0AEY7OwBfBUDg2nl0ACkkHCR5JTivNDSMkCCQnJAAUQYjNhwEko8y1Ht0zJqtAElZNRoUNviklNSAXXSQQSQAT2M-UGQjAGstJiQTJThZHSHZMlcQeZOAMxo4QTUtauyQGYAPC6ubrVLWkEx5lq0ARwYRUwdGcNFIj1S3RAhSMSAQPlQ-hAEGucCgmBOPz+6BwbAMmKUl2uakRviqWVC0yUsnhCXQCHmETRGPY8imSkwcNkEHObCMCGW2g8UAYc0w9JAiVMSERIC2RmZgkekyUqw2qFA2MlCtMzSQUDoZ1QFRAewOBmOmtOrxJd0p7KUL2txPe6AVStM2oBQNkIL0IIhSmgHnpoDUbGQoSRDkS1JASCeNERsjFgihHJARm8bEEEOtIcEYZAzpABjUcBagz2mJmieTJ1L5crewrfshqSAA):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": "container",
  "height": 250,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"Origin": "USA", "value": 100},
      {"Origin": "Japan", "value": 0},
      {"Origin": "Europe", "value": 50},
      {"Origin": "India", "value": 100}
    ]
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "Origin"},
        "x": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "params": [
        {
          "select": {"type": "point", "fields": ["Origin"]},
          "name": "mySelection"
        }
      ],
      "transform": [{"calculate": "1", "as": "barSel"}],
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "opacity": 0},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "Origin"},
        "x": {
          "field": "barSel",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "scale": {"domain": [0, 1]},
          "axis": null
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "resolve": {"scale": {"x": "independent"}, "axis": {"x": "independent"}}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Following your example, I created an empty chart in altair and added it to layout. Could you add the following code to you answer: ´alt.Chart(ds2).mark_bar(opacity=0).encode(y='x:O').add_selection(selection)´ ?

Comment: You can edit my answer and add it, since I have not worked with altair, thats why my answer was with vega-lite.